# Fetch request return NetworkError

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I try to get data from public API using fetch on JS app, but the request return error on my browser only:

> `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` .

I've try with `CURL` from my CLI and directly on browser URL, and I've my data.

I don't really understand why my fetch return no data:

```
try {
  const request = await fetch(
    'http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=onions,garlic&q=omelet&p=3',
    { method: 'GET' }
  );
  console.log(request);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Is because the domain is not https ?

The public API : http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=onions,garlic&q=omelet&p=3

Comment: Try it without the query:  http://www.recipepuppy.com/api

Comment: seems like the api is unstable.  i got it to work, then the same code would fail.

Comment: It's ok, i need to fetch from server, not client only :) Thank you !